# How to rebuild logical tree in WPF without showing window

Tags: wpf

I have a test code that add a TabItem to TabControl.

But when I try to find the TabItem by name, null is return.

I found a solution is show the window, then I can find the TabItem by name.

But when many tests are running, OutOfMemory exception is occurred because many windows are opened.

Is there another solution to rebuild logical tree without showing window?

The following is my test code

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTest2()
{
    // Arrange

    // Initilize a subVM of CMSEditorViewModel type
    var subVM = new SubViewModel();

    // Initialize a mainVM of CMSEditorMainViewModel type
    var mainVM = new MainViewModel();

    // Initialize a MainWindow of DynamicCMS.Exe.CMSEditor
    var mainWindow = new MyEditor.MainWindow();
    mainWindow.DataContext = mainVM;


    ContentPresenter presenter = new ContentPresenter();
    using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(CmsPath.DirViewWithBS + "Subscreen.xaml"))
    {
        DataTemplate template = XamlReader.Load(stream) as DataTemplate;
        presenter.ContentTemplate = template;
        presenter.Content = subVM;
    }

    // Create a TabItem of TabControl                
    TabItem item = new TabItem();
    item.Header = "Tab1";
    item.Content = presenter;
    item.Name = "tab1";

    // Get "mainTabControl" TabControl from MainWindow
    CustomTabControl tab = CmsUtil.GetControl((Visual)mainWindow.Content, "mainTabControl") as CustomTabControl;

    // Add TabItem to TabControl
    tab.Items.Add(item);


    mainWindow.Show()       // After showing window, I can find the TabItemControl

    // Act
    TabItem tabItem = (TabItem)CmsUtil.GetControl((Visual)mainWindow.Content, "tab1");

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(tabItem);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what CmsUtil.GetControl is doing internally but did you try mainWindow.FindName("tab1")?

Comment: When mainWindow.Show() is comment out, null is returned. Otherwise, an tabItem with name "tab1" is returned. So I dont' think CmsUtil.GetControl is wrong.